# What is wrong with my Jade for loop code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

These are my entire loop code of Jade

```
block content
  div(class='row')
    div(class='col-lg-12')
      h1(class='subject') 로또라이
  div(class='row')
    div(class='col-lg-8')
      - for (var i=0; i<3; i++)
      div(class='row')
        - for (var j=0; j<12; j++)
        p 1
    div(class='col-lg-4')
      div(class='row')
        h5(style='text-align:center') 대환장익명챗
      div(class='row')
        ul(id="message" class='list-group')
      div(class='row')
        form(action="", class='form-inline')
          div(class='form-group')
            input(id="m", class='form-control', autocomplete="off")
            button(class="btn btn-default") Send
      script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
      script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js")
      script(src="/javascripts/makeSocketVariable.js")
```

And these are the section has the result don't expect.

```
 div(class='row')
    div(class='col-lg-8')
      - for (var i=0; i<3; i++)
      div(class='row')
        - for (var j=0; j<12; j++)
        p 1
```

It just get result two **div** and a **p** tag. 
I expect 3 div and each 12- p tag inside that.

What is wrong with my Jade loop code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your indentation. This is fixed form

```
div(class='row')
  div(class='col-lg-8')
    - for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      div(class='row')
        - for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++)
          p #{j}
```

As you can see, you aren't nesting `p` inside for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. It absolutely makes me solve the question. However what i see in jade official code guide was the form i did before. It is weird but solved Thanks again !